# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client ORA-00903 invalid table name

Tags: oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

I'm using the sqldeveloper and have one database connection with the following connection string:
MES@//localhost:1521/xepdb1
MES is the schema owner and a select statement like this shows me what I want to see:
select count(*) from site

I'm also using Visual Studio and I'm trying to connect to the database by using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client
I'm using exactly the same connection string.
The connect to the database works fine. But I'm always getting the 00903 error.

Any idea what the problem can be ?

Many thanks in advance

I've tried also something like this:
select count(*) from mes.site

Comment: Having trouble replicating the issue. It is trivial to get `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` exceptions but very hard to get an `ORA-00903: invalid table name` exception. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/14u-WoPm)

Comment: @MT0: To be honest I don't know what the difference is. I would have expected an ORA-00942 as well. But it's always an ORA-00903

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have used quoted identifiers to create the table then you will need to use quoted identifiers (and use the same case) whenever you access the table.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MES."site" (something NUMBER);
```

Then you would need to use:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM MES."site";
```

or

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM mes."site";
```

or

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM mEs."site";
```

The `MES` schema name is unquoted so you can use any case (and Oracle will implicitly convert it to upper-case to look it up in the data dictionary); however, `"site"` is a quoted identifier and Oracle will respect the case-sensitivity of the identifier and you **MUST** use the correct case and the surrounding quotes.

You can see the exact case you need to use in the result of the query:

```sql
SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables WHERE UPPER(table_name) = 'SITE';
```

If the data dictionary shows that the table name is upper-case then you can use an unquoted identifier (assuming that all the other naming rules have been respected and the table name is not a reserved/keyword) otherwise you will need to use a quoted identifier.

---

Normally you would get the `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` exception but you can get `ORA-00903: invalid table name` when you use a keyword for a table name:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "NUMBER" (x) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NUMBER;
```

Give the exception:

> ```
> ORA-00903: invalid table name
> ```

And:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "NUMBER";
```

Works.

However, `MES` and `SITE` are not keywords that should trigger that.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uTetROCb)

Comment: I just noticed what the problem is.
I have a conversion error in my code. The select statement hasn't been converted well. So it was empty when it has been executed. That's another good reason to show the 00903 instead of the 00942.
Thanks a lot for you help